# The complexity of the algorithm with loops

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I have algorithm that contains next loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

    for (int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

I found that this algorithm has $O(n^2)$ complexity but I can't understand why? I.e. if $N = 4$ then $n^2 = 16$ but my loop has 6 iterations only. Just it's a half of $n^2$ value.

P.S. I understand never how to measure the complexity of the algorithm, I only can understand how to write it in the mathematics.

Comment: The point is that $n^2/2 = O(n^2)$.

Comment: Do we just reduce a factor?

Comment: @Шах I suggest you check the definition of [big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "stuff" will get executed $N(N - 1)/2 = 0.5N^2 - 0.5N$ times. When analyzing the asymptotic complexity, only the highest order term is kept, and multiplicative constants are removed, leaving you with $O(N^2)$.

It works this way because we're interested in what happens when $N$ goes to infinity (scalability).

Comment: It seems, I understood. Thank you for explanation!